# how to burn dvd's in ubuntu that can be watchin in dvd player

Tags: ubuntu

I used nero vision on windows that will transcode + burn dvd's which can be used in dvd player. anything similar on ubuntu?

Comment: Hello Eric. You seem to have a handful of questions that are answered but are not marked as such. Would you mind accepting the answers so they are removed from the Unanswered list and answerers get their rep? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

[GnomeBaker](http://gnomebaker.sourceforge.net/) is the default application that comes with the newer versions of Ubuntu, it should be able to handle this. There is also [K3B](http://k3b.plainblack.com/videoencoding) (my preference) which is a nice frontend and **will** do the transcoding for sure, as I've used it.

Comment: K3B is still my favorite burner on linux.

Comment: Yup, Couldn't live without it :)